# Запрос MySQL с нестандартной сортировкой

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
//mysql запрос
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `articul`
```

Собственно выдает товары. Какие то в наличии есть, каких то нету. Те что в наличии охота в начало списка, те, что не в наличии охота в конец.. но не через ORDER а что то типа

```
+---------+--------+
| articul | amount |
+---------+--------+
| 123     | 5      |
| 456     | 6      |
| 789     | 3      |
| 124     | 0      |
| 453     | 0      |
| 788     | 0      |
| 859     | 0      |
+---------+--------+

// т.е. результат
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `amount`>0 ORDER BY `articul`
+
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `amount`=0 ORDER BY `articul`
```

сейчас дело решил 2мя запросами, охота ест-но 1. Может кто подсказать, можно ли такое сделать и как?

Comment: Я бы просто добавил amount через запятую в предложение ORDER BY.

Comment: SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY field(amount,0), `articul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте сортировку по нескольким полям.

Код на [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/713e7/2).

Comment: не совсем то (т.е. фактически ORDER BY `amount` DESC) , но тоже пойдет. Хотел так -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/713e7/21, только в одной таблице. (id - 4,6,2,1,5,3,7)